# ExceptionFilterAttribute not being invoked

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

I have the following WebApiConfig.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {

        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing();
       //     config.MessageHandlers.Add(new TokenValidationHandler());
       //     config.MessageHandlers.Add(new LoggingHandler());
             config.Filters.Add(new ApiCustomExceptionHandler());
        }
```

And I implemented the ExceptionFilterAttribute as follows

```
public class ApiCustomExceptionHandler : ExceptionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
        {

        var exceptionType = context.Exception.GetType();
        if (exceptionType == typeof(UnauthorizedAccessException))
        {
            context.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
        }
```

My controller is declared thus:

```
 [ApiCustomExceptionHandler]
    public class UserManagementController : ApiController
   {
....
}
```

The problem is **OnException** never gets invoked, when I throw a UnAuthorizedAccessException. Any idea why this is so?

-Arun

Answer (score 0):

When I had this problem, it turned out actually to be an problem on one action only -- other actions in the controller were fine.  The problematic method was returning a generic (in my case,`IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>>`).  I fixed this by returning an array instead: `Dictionary<string, object>[]`.

Notice that returning a generic also gives warning [CA1006](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(CA1006);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.1)&rd=true) if you have Static Code Analysis enabled.